# Adding to Business Objects Universe

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

Basically I want to make my own objects in the Business Objects Universe. However, we get regular universe updates from the software provider. Which means anything I create will be removed when they send a new universe.

Is there a way I can create objects without them being affected by a universe update?

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of.  You can create a linked universe, which inherits the contents of an underlying universe (or universes), and allows you to add your own tables and objects (but not modify anything from the underlying universe).

If new content is added to the underlying universe, then it should just show up automatically in the linked universe, without breaking any of your additions.

This functionality has been in UDT since the early days, and was added to IDT recently -- I forget the exact version, but I think it's around BI4.2.

Comment: This sounds like it could work. I dont suppose you can point me in the direction of any websites that show how to link the universe in the way you are saying?

Comment: Here is a [link](https://help.sap.com/viewer/3d4f417fd0764f909c0ef7931e19fe1a/4.2.5/en-US/bcda2165febb4ff38b704c5bf5c9ae0c.html) to get you started.